# Rotate through DIVs via Prev & Next Button; unknown # of divs

Tags: jquery

This question is very similar to a few other questions on here, but with a twist.  The number of divs can be anything between none and a dozen, and the named DIV is the same for each object to be rotated.  Code below:

PHP:

```
if($job->getPictureGalleries() != null){
$gallerys = $job->getPictureGalleries();
foreach($gallerys as $gallery){
    $gallery = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Gallery')->find($gallery);
    echo "<div class=\"galleries\">";
    include_partial('gallery/record', array('gallery' => $gallery));
    echo "</div>";
}
if(count($gallerys) > 1){
    $buttons = <<<EOD
<table style="box-shadow: 0.2em 0.2em 0.3em grey; width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 15px; background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid grey; border-radius: 15px; height: 20px">
<tr style="width: 100%; ">
 <td style="width: 33%; text-align: right">
    <a href="#" id="previous_link"><img src="/web/images/previous.png" height="35" width="35" /></a>
 </td>
 <td style="
     width: 33%;
     color: #444444; 
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.3em grey;
 ">
    More Galleries
 </td>
 <td style="width: 33%">
    <a href="#" id="show_next_gallery" ><img src="/web/images/next_1.png" height="35" width="35" /></a></div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 EOD;
    echo $buttons;
}
};
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('.galleries').size() > 1){
   $('.galleries').hide();
   $('.galleries').first().show();

   $("#show_next_gallery").click(function() {
       $('.galleries').first().hide();
       $('.galleries').nextAll().show();
        return false;
      });

   $("#previous_link").click(function() {
       $('.galleries').hide();
       $('.galleries').prevAll().show();
        return false;
      });
}

});
```

The above code works great when only two objects are retrieved, but anything more than that and everything breaks down when the next button is clicked - resulting in multiple divs being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the elements `index()` in order to target the next/previous element. Also, you don't need to bind two separate click handlers. Just use `e.target` to determine which element was clicked:

```
$('#show_next_gallery, #previous_link').click(function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var currentIdx = parseInt($('div.galleries:visible').index('div.galleries'), 10);
    var nextIdx = ($(e.target).is('#show_next_gallery')) ? currentIdx + 1 : currentIdx - 1;
    
    $('div.galleries:eq(' + currentIdx + ')').hide();
    $('div.galleries:eq(' + nextIdx + ')').show();
    
});
```

This is a simplified answer. Obviously you'll want to add some logic for checking whether there is a next/previous element, and hide the next/previous buttons based on that, but this should get you going in the right direction.

#### [Here's a complete example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj3hK/9/)

Note: You could have used jQuery's `.next()` for this, as your `.galleries` are immediately after one another, however, as soon as you add other elements between them, the whole thing would break down. Using the index, and passing the selector in to the index ensures that you'll always get the correct element at the correct position.

Comment: Elegant solution.  I learned a lot reading all of the submitted solutions, but ultimately used yours.  Thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfect with only 2 divs because `nextAll()` gives you the only div that exists. If there are multiple divs `nextAll()` gives you all those divs except the first one.

The possible solution i can think of is assign some kind of numeric identifiers to each div like:

```
<div class="galleries" num="1">...</div>
<div class="galleries" num="2">...</div>
<div class="galleries" num="3">...</div>
```

your jquery:

```
//hide all galleries except first
$('.galleries:not([num=1])').hide();
$("#show_next_gallery").click(function() {
    var curr = $('.galleries:visible').attr('num');
    var next = curr + 1;
    $('.galleries[num='+curr+']').hide();
    $('.galleries[num='+next+']').show();
    return false;
});

$("#previous_link").click(function() {
    var curr = $('.galleries:visible').attr('num');
    var prev = curr - 1;
    $('.galleries[num='+curr+']').hide();
    $('.galleries[num='+prev+']').show();
    return false;
});
```

havent tested it but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider something like the following (takes into account that you will want to roll back to the first element when you hit the last one):

```
$('.galleries:not(:first)').hide();

$('#show_next_gallery').click(function() {
  var cur = $('.galleries:visible').hide();
  var next = cur.next();
  // Need to handle rolling to front when on last entry
  if(next.size() === 0) {
    next = $('.galleries:first');
  }
  next.show();
});

$('#show_prev_gallery').click(function() {
  var cur = $('.galleries:visible').hide();
  var prev = cur.prev();
  // Need to handle rolling to back when on first entry
  if(prev.size() === 0) {
    prev = $('.galleries:last');
  }
  prev.show();
});
```

Comment: I love your solution... almost works perfectly.  1 thing: I get a blank div at the end of the rotation.  Anyway to get rid of that?